# Script para comparação e atualização de equemas de banco de dados Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Pessoal gostaria de saber se existe algum programa (ou script) que compare esquemas e faça atualização em banco de dados, trabalhamos com um software que utiliza o banco Oracle e todas as vezes que uma atualização implica em mudanças nos esquemas do banco, precisamos atualizar tambem os  esquemas do banco em produção no cliente,  atualmente estamos fazendo isso de forma manual, e isso está nos tomando um tempo enorme, queríamos algo mais simples e rápido. Utilizamos atualmente o PL/SQL com ORACLE.

Comment: _compare e aplica bancos_ O que quer dizer?

Comment: seja mais claro por favor

Comment: Temos as tabelas no banco e temos que compara-las para saber o que mudou de uma atualização para outra e depois temos que aplicar se tiver alguma alteração (Sempre tem).

Comment: eu não utilizo essa comparação, apenas gravo em meu sistema quais atualizações tenho que realizar no banco, lá no sistema do cliente, gravo qual foi a última atualização executada (ex. Cod 21), via webservice, o sistema no cliente solicita todas as atualizações que ocorreram depois da 21, e executa todas.

Comment: O Sql Developer tem um item de menu "Diferenças de Banco de Dados" , creio que resolva sua questão. (Supondo diferença de estruturas)

Comment: [dbforge](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/schemacompare/), é uma ferramenta especializada, [esse link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_compare_schemas.htm), apresenta varias alternativas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Oracle SQL Developer oferece um recurso para comparação de databases diferentes:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acredito que com essa ferramenta seu trabalho irá diminuir.